# Strange transition behavior together with border

Tags: html, css

I want to create a navigationbar. The `<div>`s should be contained by `<a>`s. So I created the following code (reduced, webkit-only):

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <style>
        .menuStripItem {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            height: 50px;
            /* Vertical center */
            line-height: 50px;
            /* Horizontal center */
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 2px;
            /* smooth background modification */
            -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;
        }

            .menuStripItem:hover {
                background-color: lightgrey;
                border: 1px solid cadetblue;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0">
                    <li class="menuStripItem">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div>Menu1</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuStripItem">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div>Menu2</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuStripItem">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div>Menu3</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuStripItem">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div>Menu4</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When you try it, you will notice the content inside the `<div>`s bounces and one `<div>` gets pushed into a new line while hovering. That's probably because the border takes 1px.

I figured out a solution with the CSS:

```
    .menuStripItem {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 50px;
        /* Vertical center */
        line-height: 50px;
        /* Horizontal center */
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px;
        /* Ensures that adding a border doesn't increase the width of div */
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        /* smooth background modification */
        -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;
        /* Make sure content does not bounce PART1 no idea why this works*/
        -webkit-transition: font linear 1s;
    }

        .menuStripItem:hover {
            background-color: lightgrey;
            border: 1px solid cadetblue;
            /* Make sure content does not bounce PART2 */
            margin-top: -1px;
        }
```

The problem is I have no idea why this works. I found out you usually create one `Transition` with multiple properties, but when I use

`-webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s, font linear 1s;`

it doesn't work anymore. It's confusing.

Do you know what's going on? Or maybe you have a much better solution to fix the bouncing link?

Comment: +1 for *"...I have no idea why this works"* :P

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be fixed just by adding this css rule on .menuStripItem

```
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

i've created a fiddle for this.

[click for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjQ7R/)

The fix is that when there's a 1px border already there before hover, on hover it just replaces the color. However if you add a border of higher pixel on hover..you can see the bouncing effect again due to change in the border width when you hover.The HTML box model better explains this.